# Finding max of two doubles in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, double, max

I am extremely new to writing code in Swift. Only part way through one book - iOS 10 App Development Essentials by Neil Smyth. But I have a question about setting constants and specifically looking for a maximum of two doubles that were assigned.

I have the following code:

```
Let Transfer1055 = 10
Let Diameter1: Double = 6.25
Let Diameter2: Double = 8.125
Let CenterDim: Double = 12
Let StructureWidth: Double = 60
Let Rad1 = Diameter1 / 2
Let Rad2 = Diameter2 / 2
Let RadMax = Max(Rad1,Rad2)
```

The problem I am having is in the last line, I can't get the max() function to work properly. Having Diameter1 set to 6.25 and Diameter2 set to 8.125. This would make Rad1=3.125 and Rad2=4.0625. I want RadMax to equal 4.0625, then I want to use that later in the code, but I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions would help. Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, this is just preliminary code in Playground to try out writing some variables and learning how to use a few math functions.

Comment: `Let`?  – That cannot be your real code. Nothing of that compiles.

Comment: @MartinR, it looks like some Basic dialect code

Answer (score 5):

Works as expected

```
let transfer1055 = 10
let diameter1: Double = 6.25
let diameter2: Double = 8.125
let centerDim: Double = 12
let structureWidth: Double = 60
let rad1 = diameter1 / 2
let rad2 = diameter2 / 2
let radMax = max(rad1, rad2)

print(radMax) // Prints: "4.0625\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just refactor your code a little:

```
let transfer1055 = 10
let diameter1: Double = 6.25
let diameter2: Double = 8.125
let centerDim: Double = 12
let structureWidth: Double = 60
let rad1 = diameter1 / 2
let rad2 = diameter2 / 2
let radMax = max(rad1,rad2)
```

And `radMax` is equal to `rad2`.

Comment: You should not write your code this way. Capital words are not for variables and methods.

Comment: Done. I know about that rule, just save original names. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have this block on code? In playground it should work. Above viewDidLoad in a viewController it might require you to make the computed variable lazy.